# Using parallax scrolling, cube has distortion

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, 2d, parallax

I am creating a 2d platformer right now, and I decided that I would use parallax scrolling.

So what I did is I had 3 tile maps, one for the background, one for the foreground, and one for on front of the foreground.

Each tile map would display the tiles at a different size.

Background -> 48px

Foreground -> 64px

On front of foreground -> 80px

I got the pixels from looking at other 3d games(such as Minecraft), when cubes are further a way. I wanted each tile to be as if the size of it is a cube.

I used the below code to calculate where each tile goes on the screen, based on its x, y, and size.

```
x - (cameraX * size / 64) + canvas.width / 2; // 64 is the size of the texture.
y - (cameraY * size / 64) + canvas.height / 2;
```

Here was the result:

[image: Camera at the right][image: Camera at the left]

As you can see the tiles in the background are moving slower.

However, when you jump, there would be white space between the tiles:

[image]

I understand why this is happening, it is because there should be a top face on the tile (as if it is a cube), but since it is only a square, it shows white space.

So I used this code to make it look as if it is a 3d cube.

```
var i = (size - size * 0.25);

while (i < size)
{   
    ctx.drawImage(images[this.type], getProperX(x*(i), i), getProperY(y*i, i), i, i);

    // The first argument of getProperX/getProperY is the x/y, the second argument is the size of the tile.

    i += 1;
}
```

This keeps drawing loads of squares, with a size slightly smaller than the last, so that the getProperX/Y function will display it in the right place.

Now they looks like cubes, so the problem is nearly fixed:

[image]

The only problem now, is that the length of the cubes are very long when you are looking on top/bottom of it, or to the right/left of it (as if it is distorted).

[image]

Why are the cubes/tiles so long, can anyone explain to me?

How would you go about fixing something like this?

Did I do something wrong in my parallax scrolling function `getProperX/Y()`? because I don't see why there is so much space between the distant tiles and the close ones.

Thanks for all help, very appreciated.

Comment: In regards to the last image in your post: Is it your desire that the front, red platform's distant edge be in line with the near edge of the next blue platform, like a staircase?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry for not getting back to you sooner.

Comment: Ok, so you are stretching the parallax background concept too far. Will the character move up and down the staircase? Referring to the last picture in your post, will the camera move to the first blue stair from the bottom? Let me remember the equations I used to use and get back to you.

Comment: Yes. the charachter will move up and down the staircase. Yeah, the camera will be moving up and down as you move up.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this question. I can't get the perspective projection shrinking formula to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/2ps9bLff/14/

Comment: What are the offsets? Edit: It's fine I know what it is now.

Comment: The cubes are shrinking, just very little. Some of them 96% of the original size. Also it seems like the closer it is the smaller the cube. If the z is 1: `dr = 1 / (4+1) = 1/5 = 0.2`. Now further away, If the z is 64 (2 cubes away): `dr = 64 / (4+64) = 64/68 = 0.941`

Comment: I think this is what I have been looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/2ps9bLff/15/

Comment: And also these equations hate negative numbers in the z axis, so I adjusted the z loop to start at 1. Enough of that, let's get you running up some stairs.